# Why am I getting "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scripts/__init__.py'" while installing OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV on Python and unfortunately this error is causing problem and hence PyCharm cannot install it. The error message is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scripts/__init__.py'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code? Also - have you got a venv and is it activated?

Comment: I didn't code anything. Was trying to install OpenCV and getting the error. I do have a venv file but not sure whether it is activated or not.

Comment: what was your command to install OpenCV?

Comment: pip install opencv-python